# array is (800, ) dimension, each element is (240, ) dimension, how to change to (800, 240)

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

I have a np array which is (800,) in shape, and each element in this array is (240, ) in shape, how to reshape this array to (800, 240) dimension?

Comment: What is the output of `a.shape` (assuming your array is named `a`)?

Comment: the a.shape is (800, ), a[0].shape is (240,), I would like to reshape this to an array with shape (800, 240)

Comment: I can't figure out how you created an array of that shape, if you can provide a simple snippet of code it would be nice (maybe with lower dimensions :P). Just to check, have you tried: `a.reshape((800, 240))`?

Comment: I tried to reshape, it does not work. Actually, I pull out this array from a pandas column. a = df['col'].values, then a.shape is (800, ), and each element in a, the shape is (240, ), so take first element as example, a[0].shape is (240, )

Comment: Found something. Posted it as an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with [np.stack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html):

```
np.stack(a)
```

Comment: yes, it is. But I am a little bit confused, why use stack here.

Comment: I'm a bit confused too. The object you brought is new to me and my first shots (reshape and resize) didn't work. This solution works, in general, for sequences of arrays.